# How can I authenticate against AD and bind a second AD LDS Instance?

Tags: python, ldap, flask-login

I have an Active Directory that contains my users and groups.
And I have installed a server with an AD LDS instance for base dn search.

What I am trying to do is to bind the AD LDS instance simultaneously with an second user. The User has the rights on the instance.

.env

```
# Active Directory service User for Users authentication
AD_USER='CN=AD_Service,OU=Service Users,OU=Domain Users,DC=example,DC=local'
AD_PASS='SuperSecret_forAD'
AD_SERVER='ldaps://dc01.example.local'
AD_DOMAIN='EXAMPLE'

# AD LDS service User for computer device querys
ADLDS_USER='CN=ADLDS_Service,OU=Service Users,OU=Domain Users,DC=example,DC=local'
ADLDS_PASS='SuperSecret_forADLDS'

# Active Directory Users 
SEARCH_BASE='OU=Domain Users,DC=example,DC=local'

# AD LDS Server for data
ADLDS_SERVER='ldaps://ldap.example.local'
BASE_DN_PORTAL='OU=computer devices,DC=company,DC=example,DC=local'
```

authentication.py

```
def authenticate_ad(username, password):
    """
    Check authentication of user against AD with LDAP
    """
    server = Server(current_app.config['AD_SERVER'], use_ssl=True)

    try:
        with Connection(server,
                        user=f"{current_app.config['AD_DOMAIN']}\\{username}",
                        password=password,
                        authentication=SIMPLE,
                        check_names=True,
                        raise_exceptions=True) as conn:
            if conn.bind():
                logger.info(f"Authentication successful for {username} Status: {conn.result}")
                return True
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Authentication failed: {username} - {e}")
    return False
```

adlds.py

```
class ADLDSBackend:

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Check binding of AD LDS Server used authentication of user against AD
        """    
        self.server = Server(current_app.config['ADLDS_SERVER'])
        self.ldap_conn = Connection(self.server,
                                    user=f"{current_app.config['AD_DOMAIN']}\\{current_app.config['ADLDS_USER']}",
                                    password=current_app.config['ADLDS_PASS'],
                                    auto_bind=True)    
    
    def get_computer(self, computername):
        SEARCH_FILTER = f'(&(objectClass=computer)(sAMAccountName={computername}$))'
        BASE_DN = current_app.config['BASE_DN_PORTAL']

        self.ldap_conn.search(search_base=BASE_DN,
                              search_filter=SEARCH_FILTER,
                              search_scope=SUBTREE,
                              attributes=['cn', 'serialNumber', 'operatingSystemVersion', 'description'])
```

I get the message:

> ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPBindError: automatic bind not successful - invalidCredentials

The credentials are correct

Can anyone help me?
Or is there any similar example where I can orient myself? I haven't really found anything suitable on the net.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does no one have any ideas on how to solve such a problem?